# Create c or c++ program that only Use ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, linker, ntdll

I want to write a program in C or C ++ in Visual Studio that uses only the **ntdll** library and has no graphical interface. (Import functions only from **ntdll.dll**)

Can anyone guide me?

my Test code here :

```c
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return a + b;
}
```

**Update**

I made some changes in my project and set "Ignore All Default Libraries" to "yes" , put "ntdll.lib" on "additional dependency" and set "Entry Point" to "main".

But when I try to compile project I receive 3 link errors:
[image: Link Errors image]

Comment: Start with the linker options to remove all default libraries and write code until you get a linker error.  Rewrite the offending code - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zl-omit-default-library-name?view=msvc-160  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries?view=msvc-160  Use dynamic linking (LoadModule, GetProcAddress) to use function from the dlls you want to use.

Comment: Do you even need the **ntdll** library at all for the above code? Also note that `main` is usually called from the C runtime library, so if you are not linking the C runtime library, you will need to tell the linker that your `main` function is the entry point.

Comment: @IanAbbott: What do you think the `return` is going to do if the C run-time startup code has not set a return address?

Comment: I think you can be helped better if you would first follow a guide or tutorial, and specifically post things that you run into that don't work here. This way, you can ask more specific questions instead of a general one.

Comment: @Richard Critten Thanks for the comment, I read the two links and made the necessary settings, but the program has errors that I put in my questions.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Thank you for your comment.
This is not the main program I need and it is just for testing. In the main program I used a lot of ntdll library functions, based on what you said I updated my questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I guess it will set `eax` or `rax` to the return value and do a `ret`? SInce this is the entry function, the `ret` should terminate the only thread, which should result in termination of the process.

Comment: The linker errors are probably due to the "Basic Runtime Checks" and "Smaller Type Check" C/C++ code generation settings in the project. Try setting "Basic Runtime Checks" to "default", and setting "Smaller Type Check" to "No" and doing a "Release" build.

Comment: @IanAbbott: The run-time code calls `main`. When `main` returns, the run-time code calls `exit`, which executes whatever special instruction performs a system call to request that the system terminate the process. If you return from a `main` routine that you have marked as the entry point, there is no return address on the stack, because nothing has set up the stack. There is nothing to return to, and there is no call to `exit` to tell the operating system to terminate the process. Likely the program will trap with some fault.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Trying it with macOS 10.14.6, there is a 1 where `ret` picks up the return address, and the result is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I disagree. See [Terminating a Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-process) where one of the terminating events is "The last thread of the process terminates". And see [Terminating a Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-thread) where one of the terminating events is "The thread function returns". N.B. This is for Microsoft Windows since the the question is about using **ntdll.dll**.

Comment: @IanAbbott: That documentation is for normal behavior program, not situations where you have prevented a proper program build. `return` is not a magic instruction that automatically does the right thing. It loads a return address from the stack into the program counter register. If there is no correct return address on the stack, something breaks. Try it.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not building a GUI program? Please check your IDE's options. A simple console program like the one you show should have the least dependencies possible with the compiler. -- And it is nonsense to set the entry point manually, if you are not providing an own startup module.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have tried it and it works fine. The code at the entry point consisted of `mov eax,2Ah` `ret`. The exit status after running the program was 42.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Code was tiny.c `int main() { return 42; }`. Compiled in a native x64 environment with `cl /nologo /c /O1 tiny.c` `link /nologo /ENTRY:main /NODEFAULTLIB /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS tiny.obj`. `dumpbin /headers tiny.exe` shows entry point 0000000140001000 and 6 bytes of code in the .text section. `dumpbin /disasm tiny.exe` shows the instructions `mov eax,2AH` and `ret` starting at the entry point (that is the whole of the 6 bytes of code).

Comment: @IanAbbott: Interesting. So what is the return address, and who is putting it on the stack, and what is the code it returns to? And why is the linker putting that code in the executable? E.g., with the Unix linker, the default entry point is the symbol `_start`, which creates an undefined reference to `_start`, which makes the linker take the C run-time object module (which defines `_start`) from the library. The Windows linker would appear to be including some object code by default. And what you told it the entry point was may not be the real entry point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil After rebuillding with `/DEBUG:FULL` options for the compiler and linker, loading tiny.exe into WinDbg and setting a breakpoint on the entry function `main`, then when the breakpoint was reached the call stack showed `tiny!main`, `kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd`, `ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d`. This was on a Windows 7 x64 system and the program was built for x64.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's the Windows machinery for creating processes and threads that is putting the stuff on the stack for the thread entry function to return to. Nothing to do with the linker.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Thank you. I made the settings you said and the program worked properly and the errors were fixed

Comment: @the busybee. yes this is Empty Project

Comment: @IanAbbott Now try a simple program that returns its number of arguments: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { return argc; }`. What does it return on different calls? -- Ali, an empty project can be a GUI project, too. Please check the project's option.